# Laravel PHPUnit testing, weird behavior with seePageIs()

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

Trying to get the hang of testing. I have a fairly simple test just to make sure the user is kicked to login when they go to the root page:

```
public function index_without_auth_should_redirect_to_login()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');
        $response->seeStatusCode(302);
        $response->seePageIs('/login');
    }
```

This works up to the last line, where it seems like instead of checking the current path, the test itself is trying to redirect as I get this error running phpunit:

```
A request to [http://localhost/login] failed. Received status code [302].
```

Is there a different way I need to check the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're technically not on the login page just yet as you didn't follow the redirect. The exception you're getting is perfectly valid. The `seePageIs()` method [asserts if page is loaded](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0fe971b5dc41bb5afe51a530dcc17ed3d58ce19f/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php#L140-L155). It [expects](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0fe971b5dc41bb5afe51a530dcc17ed3d58ce19f/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php#L157-L180) a 200 response (while you've got a 302).

You need to follow the redirect first, or verify the `Location` header to see if you're being redirected to the login page.

You can use one of [`assertRedirectedTo()` or `assertRedirectedToRoute()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.html#method_assertRedirectedTo) assertions with the `MakesHttpRequests` trait:

```php
$this->get('/')
$this->seeStatusCode(302);
$this->assertRedirectedTo('http://localhost/login');
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. Any clue why the headers prop wouldn't work in 5.2? I'm not able to find anything in the docs: "Undefined Property: ...AuthControllerTest::$headers"

Comment: It's not a test property, but a response property. I assumed your $request is an instance of Request. Is it not?

Comment: No, I've been trying to inject Request through the test but I haven't had any luck

Comment: How does your get() method look like?

Comment: I haven't changed anything so I'm just using the default TestCase class which uses the MakesHTTPRequests trait

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by the variable name. It's techinically not a request. I updated my answer. Hope this helps!